# Error on executing Javascript, works by clicking anchor

Tags: javascript, cocoa, dom, dom-events

I have a web page I need to manipulate using either DOM or JavaScript, in a Cocoa app.

There's a link on that web page that triggers a Javascript event.

That link has only a href that points to `javascript:doThis('onThat')`

When I click that link using my browser, that works just fine, /though/ an error appears on the browser console saying that the variable `doThis` wasn't found. The Javascript, however, runs.

When I try to execute `javascript:doThis('onThat')` on the web page, by using either the evaluate Javascript command of Cocoa or on the browser's console, it doesn't work, with the error that the variable `doThis` isn't nowhere to be seen... Though, I repeat, it works just fine when I click on the anchor, and the anchor only points to that Javascript code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to execute JavaScript code on the Console, you should not be using `javascript:`, instead you just try running it by invoking the function `doThis('onThat')`. When you put a piece of JS code in the `href` attribute of an anchor element, then it signals the browser what to do, in this case the browser tries to evaluate that piece of code, and if it finds the function in that webpage it executes it else it just throws up the error.

Just try running your code without `javascript:` in the Console.

Comment: That gets me the exact same result, "can't find variable: doThis"

Comment: it means that the variable/function does not exist, are you sure that there are no duplicate variable named "doThis", because what I see from the code is `doThis` is a function not a variable. If the function exists in that page and is a Global function then it should be executed without an error. By the way when you say in your question "/though/ an error appears on the browser console saying that the variable doThis wasn't found. The javascript, however, runs." the last part of the sentence is bit confusing, can you elaborate what do you mean by "the JavaScript however runs" ?

Comment: I mean that an error that "doThis" wasn't found appears on the console, but the expected result happens.

Comment: I ended up not using JavaScript for this. Accepting your answer for your troubles.

Comment: Thanks for accepting as answer, but it still puzzles me why you're getting the error, probably a jsfiddle example could help track down the error, anyway I am glad that you've found a workaround.